# Deep Copying Attempt

Tags: java

I am trying to build a method to deep copy a class:

```
public MyClass clne() {
    MyClass cpy = new MyClass();
    cpy.var1 = getVar1(); //getVar1 is a method returning the value of var1
    cpy.var2 = getVar2();
    return cpy;
}
```

However, when I run:

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();
x.var1 = 18;
MyClass y = x.clne();
y.myMethod(); // Where myMethod is a method changing the value of var1 to, say 4.
System.out.println(x.var1);
```

The value of x.var1 is 4.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you :)

Comment: What are the types of `var1` and `var2`?  Are they `int`?  `Integer`?

Comment: Even if it was `Integer`, surely it wouldn't matter since `Integer` is immutable?

Comment: Can you show the body of `getVar1();` method?

Comment: They are int, but I tried with other mutable types (ie: string, float etc) and it gave the same error

Comment: @jonasnas:
public int getVar1() {

return var1;

}

Comment: Can you show the entire declarations of the `var1` and `var2` variables in `MyClass`?

Comment: Can you post a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Are `var1` and `var2` static?

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating a new instance of var1 rather than pointing to the old reference, unless they are primitives of course.

```
cpy.var1 = new Var1( getVar1() );
```

this will require you to write a copy constructor for whatever class Var1 is. This can be done in other ways though.

Hope that helps.

PS, you are basically doing a shallow copy.

Comment: The OP says that they are primitives, not objects

Comment: Is it new Var1 or new var1? (If it makes a difference)

Comment: Depends on the type of var1. as you assign it using x.var1 = 4, i assume it must either be an int or Integer, which means that what you wrote should be fine unless they are static members